# Trying to get equal columns with fractionally spaced gaps with Grid or Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm wondering if I'm approaching this from the wrong angle.

I'm trying to get items to be equally spaced, with a fixed (5/) number per line. There should be no left or right margins on leading or last columns. And the gutter or gap should be flexible/responsive.

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li><span>01</span></li>
  <li><span>02</span></li>
  <li><span>03</span></li>
  <li><span>04</span></li>
  <li><span>05</span></li>
  <li><span>06</span></li>
  <li><span>07</span></li>
  <li><span>08</span></li>
  <li><span>09</span></li>
  <li><span>10</span></li>
  <li><span>05</span></li>
  <li><span>06</span></li>
  <li><span>07</span></li>
  <li><span>08</span></li>
  <li><span>09</span></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1fr;
}

li {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align:center;
 }

li:nth-child(5n+1) {
  text-align:left;
}
li:nth-child(5n) {
  text-align:right;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid fuchsia;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em; 
}

/* Resets & Styling */
ul {
  background-color: lightblue;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I've also created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/skube/pen/yqGNdv)

Comment: The `fr` unit is not valid as a value for gap properties. Must be a normal length. Have you tried percentages? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBMLWP

Comment: Using percentage kinda works but still seems hackish as it relies on a 'magic' number. Also, the three inner columns are gapped differently than the outer ones.

Comment: Actually, the three inner columns *are not* gapped differently than the outer ones.The gaps are identical. But you have the content of the outer items aligned left and right using `text-align`. https://i.imgur.com/JFL8dZA.png

Comment: Yes, as the intent is to have the outer columns flush against the container.

Comment: If you look at the image I provided, the outer columns are indeed flush against the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/LBMjoe

**Update: have added vendor prefix for IE11 support**

The important bits are that I changed your grid

```
ul {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr auto 1fr auto;
   grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto 1fr auto;
}
```

and I set the alignment of all the list items to center

```
li {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

As a small detail, I also added body to the resets at the end of the reset block.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I usually associate `auto` with maximal values, but here it appears to represent minimal ones?

Comment: @skube, the clearest definition for why auto behaves as it does in this situation is on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns . You could also replace auto with a unit which matches the width of your list items, eg 2.5em, and it works equally well.

Comment: Hi @skube, I've updated my pen to include vendor prefixes for IE11. I can't confirm because I don't have that browser, so let me know how it goes.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the prefixes don't make it work in IE11. All the circles just pile up on top of each other. I think it may be a lost cause.

Comment: hey @skube, could you please see how this looks for you on IE? https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/KBJyJR

Comment: Yep definitely works in IE11! Seems like a pain but I guess that's IE11 for you. 

Comment: Excellent @skube, I'll update my answer with more of an explanation when I get a chance.